# Bacula 13 upgrade on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: upgrade, backup, repository

I've been running the community version of Bacula on Ubuntu for years from the default Ubuntu Universe repository taking whatever updates go with it. That leaves me at 9.6.7 on Ubuntu 23.04. There are some features I want in later versions of Bacula, 13.x is apparently the latest.

How do I upgrade? What repository, any conversion tool for the current working instance?

Comment: See https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/bacula . The package needs a new volunteer at Debian to maintain the package. That volunteer will import and package the new version. If no community member steps forward to volunteer, then it's time to find a new backup application. Whoever loves Bacula and is willing to volunteer to learn the packaging process can start their journey at http://mentors.debian.net . A few months after Debian, the package will merge to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [official Bacula repos](https://www.bacula.org/packages/65f518dfc0382/debs/13.0.4/dists/) only support Ubuntu LTS versions - that is 20.04 and 22.04.

If you're running a non-LTS version (like 23.04), you'll have to stick with the versions in the Universe repository, or compile your own version.

If you're on a supported LTS version, there is an [official installation guide](https://bacula.org/whitepapers/CommunityInstallationGuide.pdf) that details every installation step of the newest versions.